# Facebook realtime update does not push checkins to business page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I have realtime updates setup for an application to get realtime updates for page fields feed and checkin.

Permissions for the application are:

```
create_event 
create_note  
email  
export_stream  
friends_location  
manage_notifications  
manage_pages  
photo_upload  
publish_actions  
publish_checkins  
publish_stream  
read_friendlists  
read_page_mailboxes  
read_stream  
share_item  
sms  
status_update  
user_online_presence  
user_photos  
video_upload  
xmpp_login
```

To test this I created a page and then subscribed the application to get realtime updates for this page.

I did this by sending a post request to `/PAGE_ID/tabs` with the relevant auth token and `app_id` as my application id on the graph explorer, which returned `true`, while I get push notifications for posts, I still do not get them for checkins.

I have added a location for the business page in Facebook and it appears when users search for the place name on their mobile.

Am I missing anything? Or is it the checkins have been deprecated?

Comment: had any progress in here? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Yeah the checkins real time updatez started working, it took abt 2 days for them to become active.

Comment: +1 thanks for your reply. Would you have any code to share?

Comment: sure! i'll dig thru and share gists!

Comment: hi! not much on the code side, but you have to ensure you provide the address for your location, thereafter when the location starts appearing on near by places in a mobile phone listing, checkin using the mobile phone, I don't remember the exact number, but after certain number of checkins the checkin push update starts working.

Comment: the JSON I get from Facebook looks like this: {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"195305807173113","time":1369397786,"changes":[{"field":"checkins"}]}]}

Comment: does it work with API 2.2? can you please share the code?